# wp mail smtp earlier version

Tags: wp-mail, phpmailer, smtp

Dose anyone have an earlier version of the plugin wp mail smtp? It doesn't work when I update the plugin. Send the earlier version to my email admin@cding.xyz will be appreciatted. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this SVN depot ?
https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-mail-smtp/tags/

Comment: Great! Can it be download as a file?

Comment: Go here then : https://github.com/awesomemotive/wp-mail-smtp/releases